# R: efficient and fast splitting large data files in a directory by a variable and write out the files

Tags: r, performance, large-data, large-files

I have come into a problem regarding how to fast and efficient read and split a list of very large transaction data files by a column called ***SecurityID***, inside each transaction data file, there can be different amount of transactions per SecurityID, and for each transaction day the Security ID might not be the same. After splitting the data by SecurityID, I want to write out the output into smaller csv files, each csv file is by SecurityID. The additional function is to detect when a new transaction data file is read in, are the same SecurityID output exists, if so, append the new data to the old SecurityID.csv, if not, then create a new one.

I have attached my codes below, it does work on a small set of data. However on the full set of data it is very very slow. This prompted me to think there is a better, faster strategy to do this. And yes, unfortunately I only have my Mac to do this.

To put the file sizes into perspectives:
Each transaction data (a day) files is about 7-10GB, I have 10 years worth of data, and only processing them year by year. My mac memory is 32GB, and I think the memory is certainly a problem, Rstudio has been in a whitescreen state for 3days, and it continue to write files.

I think I have to figure out some ways to vectorise this code better, and perhaps utlise parallel processing.

set working directories etc.

```
# Input of market and transaction data
external.dir <- "my external hard drive"
input.dir.marketdata <-  file.path(external.dir,"marketdata")


# create output of market and transaction data

dir.create(file.path(external.dir, "market_data_split"))

out.dir.marketdata <- file.path(external.dir, "market_data_split")
```

First load a couple libraries

```
# loading libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)
library(data.table)
```

Then set the column to split by

```
# Define col to split by as global var
col <- "SecurityID"


# Split and write out the market data
files <- list.files(input.dir.marketdata, pattern = '*MarketData.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
files


 for (i in seq_along(files)) {

    input.dat <- data.table::fread(files[i],header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

    sptdf <- split(input.dat, input.dat[[col]])

    outfile <- as.character(unique(names(sptdf)))

    for (j in seq_along(outfile)) {

      new_data <- sptdf[[outfile[j]]]

      outfile.name <- paste0(outfile[j], ".csv")

      check.files <- list.files(out.dir.marketdata, pattern = "*.csv")

      if (outfile.name %in% check.files) {
        print(paste0(outfile.name, " already exisit!"))
        exisiting.data <- data.table::fread(file.path(out.dir.marketdata,outfile.name),
                                            header =TRUE,stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
        combined_data <- rbind(exisiting.data, new_data)
        data.table::fwrite(combined_data,
                           file = file.path(out.dir.marketdata, outfile.name),
                           row.names = FALSE,
                           quote = FALSE)
        gc()
     } else {
            print(paste0(outfile.name, " is a new data!"))
            data.table::fwrite(new_data,
                               file = file.path(out.dir.marketdata, outfile.name),
                               row.names = FALSE,
                               quote = FALSE)
            gc()
     }
    }
 }
```

Comment: If put together, is the data larger than memory? Because you may be able to vectorize some steps that are currently performed inside the nested loops, over a single large list

Comment: A few things I spotted:

Comment: You are re-creating the `check.files` object inside the nested loop for every iteration, but this object is a constant, and does not depend on the iteration objects. You could move this step outside the loops.

Comment: you are printing the "existing/new file" statement to the console. This will hardly ever be useful. Maybe we could store those statements in a vector or list?

Comment: You could create all files, then index as new or existing data, then subset the list with that index, and finally loop-write.

Comment: @GuedesBF Thank you mate, your points are absolutely true. I guess I will need to update the post to reflect the sizes of the files. But yes, the memory is definitely a problem (Rstudio is at whitescreen state for 4 days, and till writing files)

Comment: @GuedesBF can you elaborate on how to create all files, and index as new or existing data.....?

Comment: Not sure whether it is relevant in your case, but external hard drives can be also rather slow in file IO operations (depending on how they are connected), same goes for network drives. So maybe caching (some) files on the internal hard disk may help.

Comment: good suggestion @thothal I did find that too. Initially I was trying to read and write into the same external harddrive, and it was painfully slow. It got better when I;m reading from one harddrive and write to another.... in reality my total data are much larger than even the ones I described. For a single year's full set of data, it is sitting on a 18T harddrive and the portion im prioritising is 4TB, hence my 500GB internal hard disk wont do the full job.

Comment: You don't need to check or read the existing data; just use `fwrite(..., append = TRUE)`.

Comment: Why are you using R for this? Use shell tools such as awk.

Comment: @Roland well, unfortunately the reason is I only know R and a little bit python...

Comment: @MikkoMarttila sorry what do you mean by that? I guess you were referring to the if (outfile.name %in% check.files) {} bit? if i dont check if there is an existing file, wont it write out another file with the same name? I guess my understanding of fwrite(append=T) is it is only appending data split from the 1 "mother file" it read in. Will it work if the code read in another marketdata and split it? I thought the previous marketdata read in would be removed from memory so as the outfiles from it.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila full acknowledgement that I have no clue how is it working under the hood.

Comment: @ML33M using `append = TRUE` will write to the end of the file on disk if it exists, or create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @ML33M Then it might be time to learn. I'm not very familiar with these tools myself but I wouldn't use R if I had such massive data.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila thank you so much, you are right, I went back to read the R documentation about fwrite, wow man, I have learned new things.

Comment: @Roland  you are absolutely right, I have access to computing clusters at work, and I started to learn the basics of bash script... Just default to my most accustomed language once im under the heat.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila sorry man, I have a new question regarding fwrite (append=T) tested on a new data set. Frankly I made a mistake when I only added append = T to the first if else bit, where a file alread exist in the dir. So if the file is new, it will just do fwrite. To my suprise, the fwrite just keep overwriting the files, as when I checked the first file output would be dated 20210104 data, and after running a while, the data size had a minium increase, and all the data is 20210109. When I added the append =T to both if else, this fixed the problem. But I have difficulty understanding this